# Getting MVC/cshtml/vbhtml pages working on IIS8

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, razor

Been on this for hours...

New Windows 2012 server, fresh IIS 8 installation with all asp.net, 3.5, 4.5, ISAPI extensions/filters/whatever all installed.

Application pool is 4.0 and integrated mode. This is only website using that app pool.

Try and run website with index.vbhtml as default document (after adding it to default documents) and I get "cannot server this sort of page" "explicitly forbidden".

I look at "handler mappings" in IIS manager. .vbhtml is set to "forbiddenhandler" so I changed it to "System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".

Now I just get "The DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest method is not supported by IIS integrated pipeline mode"

I'm now stuck! What's the problem with this darned server please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS shouldn't directly serve those files, they are rederred through the MVC pipeline through a controller. If you have a file say, `/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`, you should be navigating to `http://siteurl/home/index` to see the content from that page via the Index action on your Home controller.

**NOTE:** Based on comment thread below, OP's underlying issue appears to have been with the installation (or lack of) ASP.NET MVC (or a corrupted installation, as he states in the comments that he did have it installed)

Comment: Yeah but I'm not trying to go to the .vbhtml file directly, I've got a default action on my controller that loads up my #home route and it's just not working.  Works fine on a shared host, but not on this IIS server I have to configure :-(

Comment: vbhtml files should NEVER be served through IIS, your shared host is misconfigured

Comment: You're getting the total wrong end of the stick here.  The SITE works on shared host. I've copied it to my IIS server. It does not work there.  I am not trying to directly access .vbhtml pages, I am using the default action of the controller. Something is misconfigured on the IIS, I don't know what that is.

Comment: My answer is based on this paragraph of your question `Try and run website with index.vbhtml as default document (after adding it to default documents) and I get "cannot server this sort of page" "explicitly forbidden".`

Comment: Yes... the website is configured with "index.vbhtml" as one of the default documents. As I have repeatedly stated I am NOT trying to go to `www.mysite.com/index.vbhtml`. My controller is configured with a default route which should kick in when I go to `www.mysite.com` and it will redirect me to `www.mysite.com/#home`.  Just because you have misinterpreted my question as meaning I am trying to directly load a .vbhtml page does not mean that's what I'm actually trying to do!

Comment: shot in the dark... did you install asp.net mvc on the server? Or did you bin deploy? Your question is very misleading when you say you set the default document, you should never have to do this, nor adjust the handlers for that type of file when deploying an mvc site.

Comment: It's not my server, it's a customer's. How would I check on the mvc installation?  I publish websites to a local directory than copy those files across to deploy. No ftp on the server.

Comment: Hmm. I did have asp.net mvc 4 installed but I installed the bundle version too and I got past the initial error. I then removed asp.net mvc 4 from programs and it has moved me on. Still some script errors to sort, but getting there so thanks for the pointer.

Comment: glad that it helped. I edited my answer to note that the answer was more thoroughly answered here in comments and that it appeared to be more closely related to a corrupted install or lack of asp.net mvc